# udp socket connection between javascript (on web page) and mc on local network

Tags: php

This *must* be simple and I suspect I have disappeared down the wrong rabbit hole.

I have the apache http server running on a pi serving pages (LAMP server) exposed through our domestic router. I can get php to serve up the material I want, and thought it would be easy to get php (on the server) to talk via sockets to another machine on the local network (ie 192.168.1.73 for example)

I can get data from a web page via the server to the local machine, but cannot get the server to receive messages from the local machine.  In php the call to
'''
socket_bind(...)
'''
gives the error
"unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address"

Don't know where the 99 is coming from; installed and ran ufw to open the port I'm using (would not have thought that was necessary or desirable but tried it anyway)

Any help greatly appreciated.
P

### It is a PHP problem.

Implemented "quote of the day" in java, running the client on the same machine as my problematic php, and the quote server on another machine on the local network.  That works fine.  replace the java client with this php client:

```
    <?php
      $server_ip = '192.168.1.78';
      $port = 41235;
      $message = 'hello world.';
      $buf = [];
      $skt = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die(..);
      socket_sendto($skt,$message,strlen($message),0,$server_ip,$port);
      // message is successfully sent and received at other end...
      socket_bind($skt,$server_ip,$port)
        or die("Could not bind socket\n");
      // the bind fails
      $bc = socket_recvfrom($skt,$buf,256,0,$server_ip,$port);
      echo "Got $bc bytes back";
   ?>
```

Fails as above with error [99]

Comment: can you connect via netcat to the "quote of the day" server ? Put you  `socket_recvfrom` code in a while loop: https://riptutorial.com/php/example/23035/udp-server-socket

Comment: changing the line to ```socket_bind($skt,"0.0.0.0",$port) ``` changes the error to [22] - a different error message! "Invalid argument in line 7".  I _think_ this method is doing a call-by-reference to change $port so that recvfrom is listening on the right port for the return message? Same with ip for some reason? making that a variable with the value 0.0.0.0 does NOT change the error.

Comment: Looking at netcat - the problem is I don't understand the behaviour or php and don't see how netcat will help but... And yes, without the loop I only get the first few bytes of the return message in java as well - left it out for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The use-case is to run a server on a machine inside a local network -lets call it insideServer, and have requests from a webpage hosted on a machine, outsideServer, responded to by code running on insideServer.  Why?  InsideServer's server is written in java because I like it.  The right way to do this was, in the old days, to have java running on the user's machine as an applet;  The modern way would be to have outsideServer run Apache Tomcat.  I don't however have the luxury of doing that so how does one forward requests?

The solution is to have a PHP script in the relevant directory of outsideServer that connects via sockets to insideServer where insideServer's code can be in whatever you want.  The PHP has however been problematic.  This code does work however:

```
$insideServerIP = '192.168.1.78';
$insideServerPort = 41234;
$message = 'pretend message from web page form';

$skt = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("create failed: " . socket_last_error());
socket_connect($skt, $insideServerIP, $insideServerPort) or die("connect failed: " . socket_last_error());
socket_write($skt, $message, strlen($message));
$in = socket_read($skt, 256, PHP_BINARY_READ);
echo "$in\n";
socket_close($skt);
```

My research over the last few days (Arr!!!) suggests nobody knows how socket_bind() is meant to work, and it turns out you don't need it!
Please do post comments (or a better answer) if there are mistakes, but this solution works I believe.

P

Comment: What about WebSockets?  A question I asked myself later. Another day and I conclude that this post is right: https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/9/24/websockets-101/ In summary, https everywhere means all the complexity is not needed.